# When creating a new record in Laravel, I am unable to obtain relation data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm basically trying to save comments in my database, so when a new comment is created, I want a newly created comment object with user details, but I can't figure out how to do this.
here is store method in my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'comment' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $comment = Comment::create([
            'ticket_id' => $request->ticket_id,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'comment' => $request->comment,
        ]);
        return response()->json($comment);
    }
```

Response

```
{
    "ticket_id": 19,
    "user_id": 1,
    "comment": "dummy comment",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-16T12:32:31.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2022-07-16T12:32:31.000000Z",
    "id": 33
}
```

In Comment Model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Expecting Result

```
{
    "id": 26,
    "comment": "new commnet",
    "ticket_id": 19,
    "user_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-07-16T12:16:19.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-16T12:16:19.000000Z",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "admin@localhost",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2022-07-16T08:35:04.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-16T08:35:04.000000Z",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Comment Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

when get comments with user

```
$comments = Comment::with('user')->get();
```

**Edit**

if you want use user object directly when create

*if user is me*

```
$comment = Comment::create([
        'ticket_id' => $request->ticket_id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'comment' => $request->comment,
    ]);
$comment['user'] = auth()->user();
return response()->json($comment);
```

**Last Edit** *it's work*

```
return response()->json($comment->load('user'));
```

Comment: This should work fine, but when I create a new comment, I want the newly created comment to have a user object.

Comment: I edit my answer . I hope my answer is what you are looking for

Comment: I don't think that is good practice

Comment: try this return response()->json($comment->load('user'));